# How can I disable requiring types for collection literals in Dart?

Tags: dart, lint

I'm currently using the `pedantic` package for my dart/flutter linting.

My `analysis_options.yaml` look like

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    always_specify_types: true
    omit_local_variable_types: false
```

I like having to specify types when I declare a variable line. But with this, I have to also specify the type on the created list/map.

The issues I have are the parts within **

```
const int number = 5;
const bool isTrue = false;
const String myName = 'Dan';
const List<int> numbers = **<int>**[1, 2, 3, 4];
const Map<String, int> ages = **<String, int>**{'Dan': 1};
```

It's redundent. How can I set my analysis_options.yaml to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with: `const List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];` and `const Map<String, int> ages = {'Dan': 1};`?

Comment: I should add that it always sounds like a great idea to specify types everywhere but in a lot of cases you can end up shooting yourself in the foot because you end up forgetting some part of the generic part of the type and ends up with a dynamic types which removes the analyzer's ability to statically determine types. Of course, this is only a problem if you are not careful but I don't really think it adds enough value relative to the amount of caution you have to add every time you are define a variable where the type comes from a function. (but this is just my personally opinion)

Comment: The issue with not specifying it is that the linter tells me I should `Specify type annotations`

Comment: I got the problem now but don't have any solution for it unfortunately.

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to have the behavior you want. (You can check the [full list of lints](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/).) You explicitly asked for `always_specify_types`, so that's what you must do: *always* specify them, even if they're redundant.  Additionally, `always_specify_types` goes against the Dart team's [preferred style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables).